# Mixing immutable and mutable structures inside the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have some pretty big request, I don't want to make it all immutable and saved to state because it's slow. I'd like to set it as a normal JS mutable object somewhere, and work on it inside the action creators, dispatching only little parts and making them immutable.

Where should I keep this mutable data? I've been thinking about the state, but how should the reducer look like?:

```
case GET_ALL:
    return state.merge({
        data: action.response
    })
```

Right now my reducers contain only pure functions containing merges that automaically create immutable objects.

Comment: I could not understand your argument, what is slow updating the state or rendering the state? Are you using plain JS objects currently or some immutability library? How big is your current state object?

Comment: Updating the state is slow, more specifically - merge operation (deeply converting JSON to immutable).

Comment: Try to measure the merge function execution time with `console.time() and console.timeEnd()`. It's a good idea also to avoid storing all the result data, take only what's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with mutable or immutable data, all you have to make sure is to return a **new** state (`newState !== state`) on state changes.

```
return { ...state, data: action.response}
```

How you are storing the data does not matter.